# Why does this loop not run the 'if statement'?

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

I have no idea why this C code isn't working. Everything works until the if statements in the loop. The question is basically to use a Caesar encryption to print the cipher text.

[image: This is how the program runs] .I've uploaded a screenshot of the issue. I'm using the CS50 IDE on GitHub.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if( argc == 2 )
    {
        printf("Success");
       printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
        return 1;
    }

    char pt[100];
    char ct[100];
    int key = (int)(argv);
    /*(if(key < 0)
    {
        printf("Integer input only");
        return 1;
    }*/

    printf("plaintext:  ");
    get_string("%s",pt);
    for (int i=0, n=strlen(pt);i<n;i++)
    {
        printf ("#");
        if (islower(pt[i]))
        {
            ct[i] = (((( pt[i] + key )) - 97) % 26) + 97;
        }
        else if (isupper(pt[i]))
        {
            ct[i] = (((( pt[i] + key )) - 65) % 26) + 65;
        }
        else
        {
            ct[i] = pt[i];
        }
    }

    for (int x=0, n = strlen(ct);x<n;x++)
        printf("ciphertext: %c \n",ct[x]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What branch of the print is supposed to be executed? PS: post also the output as text, please,not as a screenshot.

Comment: Could you please adjust the indentation of your code, it makes it easier for others to read it and for you to see problems yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem:

- Variable pt[] is empty after calling get_string()

Doc:

- https://man.cs50.io/3/get_string
- get_string - prompts user for a line of text from stdin and returns it as a string

Use code:

```
char *pt;
pt = get_string("plaintext:  ");
```

Comment: thanks for the help. That was the issue with the code

Comment: @Omar: If this was the solution, can you please mark it as the correct answer please?